# Connection Closed Gracefully on win server 2012

Tags: delphi, windows-server-2012, datasnap

In our company we have a win app that developed by xe7 and datasnap.
Its server works fine on win server 2003 but when we try to run it on a server with win server 2012 we get "Connection Closed Gracefully" error.
I search the stackoverflow and googled it, but cannot find any solution.
can anybody help me?
thanks

Comment: Have you checked the 2012 firewall?

Comment: thanks for speedy answer! yes my server firewall is off.

Comment: Your 2012 runs without firewall, totally unprotected? Instead of allowing only connections on specific ports?

Comment: Now we are in test time. first i want to it works correctly and then, 
certainly i set the firewall.

Comment: You've given zero useful details here, other than the name of the OS you're running. We're not able to just speculate on what might be causing the issue with an app we know nothing about running on a server where we have no details about configuration.

Comment: Thanks Ken for your replay. please tell me about the DETAIL that you want. I said only about the OS because my datasnap sever was worked correctly on win server 2003 for a long time and give the error on win server 2012 (client gives the error when want to connect to server via TCP/IP)<br/> in addition to our datasnap server uses RSA/PC1 Filter and both libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are in server exe app folder (like in win 2003)

Comment: Have you verified (with netstat -abon or TCPView) that the Datasnap server is listening on its TCP port?

Comment: Do you use any antivirus there, like Eset?

Comment: Now I test it(netstat -abon), my Datasnap sever is listening on port 501 (as I want) and also can see on details tab on task manager. All thing seems to be OK but clients still give me the gracefull error. I think it is something related to libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll files.

Comment: For test purpose try to connect without any filters.

Comment: Also see this : http://www.bobswart.nl/weblog/Blog.aspx?RootId=5:5039

Comment: thanks @smooty86, No i have not any antivirus. (certainly we have it after test period but now we have not any)

Comment: thanks Val Marinov for your good idea. I test it and without filters is works well.

Comment: thanks a lot for all my friends, finally it is solved by using new version of libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll (i.e. 1.0.2.8) and rebuild server and client totally.